# Is FastAI performing transfer learning when calling a vision learner?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning, fast-ai

```
learn = vision_learner(dls, models.resnet18)
```

In the above code snippet, I am calling a Vision Learner Resnet 18 model using FastAI and passing in a Dataloader containing my data.

I wonder if this process is performing any transfer learning within this call? As I am passing in my data to the vision learner.

It is important for the task I am carrying out that none is being performed at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

FastAI's [vision_learner](https://docs.fast.ai/vision.learner.html#vision_learner) has a `pretrained` argument designed specifically for that purpose. By default it is set to `True`, so in your case you would want to disable it:

```
learn = vision_learner(dls, models.resnet18, pretrained=False)
```

Comment: Does the pre-trained attribute not download a model pre-trained on ImageNet? For my case pre-training on an ImageNet is fine. It's Transfer learning on my particular data `dls`  that I am looking to avoid.

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer learning"?

Comment: Possibly a better phrased question, would be what is passing `dls` within the vision learner call doing to the retrieved model? How is it using the data within `dls`?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a learner, which is a fastai object that combines the data and a model for training, and uses transfer learning to fine tune a pretrained model in just two lines of code:

```
learn = vision_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=error_rate)
learn.fine_tune(1)
```

If you want to make a prediction on a new image, you can use learn.predict

If normalize and pretrained are True, this function adds a Normalization transform to the dls